# Hadoop and Spark Concurrency Issue

Tags: hadoop, analytics, bigdata, apache-spark

I have a data set that looks like this *input1* *input2*  to *input6* and a function to process each input as *ProcessFunc(input)*.

My problem is that when i run single hadoop map task or single spark executor the processing time of each input is identical lets say processing time of first input =  processing time of second input = ... = processing time of 6th input = *t*, however when i double the number of hadoop map tasks or spark executors lets say to *2* the processing time of each input double to *2t* which is weird.

If i further doubled the number of map tasks or spark executor by *n* the processing time doubles as *nt*.

Notes:

- I configured each of hadoop and spark to allocate one virtual core to each map task or executor.
- Based on my configuration the map tasks or spark executors should run in parallel as there are enough resources. I can see the output of each process concurrently printed however the processing time is doubled as i illustrated previously.

Is that a normal behavior from hadoop and spark? shouldn't parallel execution preserve the same processing time for each input but execute concurrently on multiple inputs?
What i expected is that 2 map tasks will process the 6 inputs in half time of processing the 6 inputs with one map task so what am i missing here?

EDIT:

Added the code for the processing function:

P.S: I know this is not the ideal way for word count, however this is not my main issue, what i am testing here is the concurrency for the processing part.

Python Code:

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, StorageLevel


    confobj = SparkConf().setAppName("MainApp")
    sc = SparkContext(master="local[2]", sparkHome="/home/spark-1.1.0", conf=confobj)

    input_path = "./input.seq"
    inputobject = sc.sequenceFile(input_path,
                               keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",  
    valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable").repartition(2)    




    def mapfunc(input):


        # The input sequence file is arranged as Key, Value
        # where Key is text file name and value is text file content
        start = datetime.now()

        # Get File Name
        filename = str(input[0])

        # Get File content
        filecontent = input[1]

        # Split at whitespaces to count words
        counts = len(filecontent.split(" "))


        end = datetime.now()

        print (end-start).seconds


        # Return file name and word counts
        return (filename, counts)


    output = inputobject.Map(mapfunc).collect()
```

Thanks All,

Comment: Could you post the code in the question? This could be a code issue. As you would expect, this is not the expected general behavior.

Comment: Added pseudo code check the original post.

Comment: Pseudocode won't really help, you should post the actual Spark code if you can.

Comment: @Developer The pseudo-code is insufficient. How are you creating the RDD. What should that process do?

Comment: Plz check now the code, and again i know word count is a hello world in hadoop and spark and it is not my target here, what i want to know is why processing time double with number of parallel tasks?

Comment: the time you are measuring is `(end-start).seconds` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, just the processing time of the text file which should be constant lets say textfile 1 takes 2 seconds if only one core processed it and textfile2 takes 2 seconds also and so on. If i have two mappers the time "(end-start).seconds for each file becomes 4 or 3 seconds and this is odd. the two processes are completely independent as i understand, no disk I/O, no shared objects why the processing time changes like that?

Comment: They do share Disk I/O. The file will be read at the moment the RDD is materialized, which is at `.collect()`. Want to compare apples to apples? Then, before the map, do a `inputobject.cache` `inputobject.count` to cache all data in memory.

Comment: Will try it and tell you what I got.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but i tried what you told me to do but no difference, i even replaced the line count code with dummy for loop and some mathematical calculations to make sure there is no IO disk, however i still get the same results.

Comment: How is Hadoop involved in all this?  All I see is a local Spark instance with 2 task slots.  How many cores does your machine have available?

Comment: I have the same code for hadoop and i have the same issue with time, the machine has 4 physical cores and Intel Hyperthreading technology so this yields 8 logical cores.